# Make EditText grow in height to show whole text content

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring

I have an EditText that consists of a spannable string.

The spannable string shows its spans as BitmapDrawables (converted from a linear layout).

At all points, I want the EditTexts height to be exactly as big as it has to be to show the whole content:

[image]

It grows as i enter more text, but making a span at the end of the line doesnt make it grow.
The third tag that is being cut off in the following screenshot was added to the text after the second tag. The edittext did not resize in this case. (I scrolled to the first line, as you would only see the third tag directly after entering it)

[image]

How can I make sure the edittext grows as the content increases?
Its vertical layout param is set to wrap_content.
Vertical layout param is NOT match_parent, as the edittext would be bigger than one line when it is empty.

EditText: (C#)

```
.SetSingleLine(false);
.SetMaxLines(10);
.SetMinLines(1);
InputType = InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine,
movementMethod = new ClickableMovementMethod(); //Custom MovementMethod inheriting from LinkMovementMethod

.SetScroller(new Scroller(Context));
.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
.SetScrollContainer(true);
```

Comment: Did you tried 
**android:inputType="textMultiLine"**

Comment: it is set to multiline

Comment: Post xml here please

Comment: I don't have an xml of that, it is actually completely in c# + xamarin.android. Only the tags are done in an xml, but they are a simple linearlayout with a textview that has the text as the span text and a drawable right (the cross icon you see in the screens)

Comment: If its `xamarin` then you should add `xamarin` tag except using repeated tags .

Comment: it doesnt matter, it can be java for android or c# for xamarin.android, i can translate it. i just think that the android community is bigger, so id might get more response by focusing on that